# Not getting correct div id while selecting multiple div using Selenium FindElements()

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to search all the `div` under specified `XPath`with `div id`. `div id` gets randomly generated and not fix so searching with partial id method as some text of `div id` is constant.`_ariaId_` is id which will be constant and numbers will get attached to it's trail.

**HTML page code.**

```
//some more HTML code before this. Trimmed for clarity.

<div tabindex="-1" data-convid="AAQkADBjMGZiZGFlLTE4ZmEtNGRlOS1iMjllLTJmOGZkNGRhZmIzNQAQAOTK5G8Pok9JkIMV8KU8bI4=" 
     data-time="2017-03-01T20:35:37+05:30" id="_ariaId_299">
</div>
<div tabindex="-1" data-convid="AAQkADBjMGZiZGFlLTE4ZmEtNGRlOS1iMjllLTJmOGZkNGRhZmIzNQAQAOTK5G8Pok9JkIMV8KU8bI4=" 
     data-time="2017-03-01T20:29:41+05:30" id="_ariaId_281">        
</div>
<div tabindex="-1" data-convid="AAQkADBjMGZiZGFlLTE4ZmEtNGRlOS1iMjllLTJmOGZkNGRhZmIzNQAQAHnhaFwb40sGj+pN9p736NE=" 
     data-time="2017-03-01T20:25:14+05:30" id="_ariaId_271">
```

**The code I'm using** to fetch all data matching the search criteria which will also include `div id`.

```
IWebElement baseTable = driverGC.FindElement(By.ClassName("conductorContent"));
        // gets all table rows
        ICollection<IWebElement> rows = baseTable.FindElements
        (By.XPath("//*[@id='primaryContainer']/div[5]/div/div[1]/div/div[4]/div[3]
                  /div/div[1]/div/div/div/div[5]/div[4]/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]/div/div/div[2]
                  /div[starts-with(@id, '_ariaId_')]"));
        foreach (var row in rows)
        {
            //Do something....
        }
```

This is giving me the desired multiple `div` which satisfy the condition **BUT**
I am getting incorrect `id`
**Expected**

[image]

**Current**

While debugging getting below data in id.

[image]

I'm stuck on this with no clue from where these `ids` coming from. Other fields are getting correctly.

Comment: The Element id you are seeing is not the id of HTML element but of IWebElement

Comment: Ohh!, I was suspicious about that. Thanks for clarifying. Could you please advise how could I get the `div id`?

Comment: how about trying element.GetAttribute("id");?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `{Element(id=0.0xxxxxx)}` you are seeing is not the id of HTML element, but the id of IWebElement.

If you want to fetch the id's of all individual HTML elements, try this

```
foreach(var row in rows) 
{
   string elementID = row.GetAttribute("id");
 }
```